# I have a problem with deploy rancher on aws eks

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, rancher, ingress-controller

Greeting Everyone:

I have a problem with deploy rancher on aws eks. Please help me why I can't deploy rancher .

This is my step to deploy rancher.

1. create aws eks

```
❯ cat eksctl-install.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Debug 20220618
set -ex

# Variable
CLUSTER_NAME=tester2
VERSION=1.25
REGION=ap-northeast-1
NODEGROUP_NAME=linux
NODE_TYPE=t2.small
NODES=2

# Main()
eksctl create cluster \
    --name ${CLUSTER_NAME} \
    --version ${VERSION} \
    --region ${REGION} \
    --nodegroup-name ${NODEGROUP_NAME} \
    --node-type ${NODE_TYPE} \
    --nodes ${NODES}

# Show
aws eks update-kubeconfig --region ${REGION} --name ${CLUSTER_NAME}
echo "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"
kubectl get svc
kubectl get nodes

# Slack,TG
# add your notify to make your like work smooth
```

2. Follow helm install cert-manager
   https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/getting-started/quick-start-guides/deploy-rancher-manager/helm-cli

```
helm repo add rancher-latest https://releases.rancher.com/server-charts/latest
kubectl create namespace cattle-system
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.11.0/cert-manager.crds.yaml
helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io
helm repo update
helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace cert-manager \
  --create-namespace \
  --version v1.11.0
```

deploy rancher

```
helm install rancher rancher-stable/rancher \
  --namespace cattle-system \
  --set hostname=dograbbit.org \
  --set bootstrapPassword=admin \
  --set ingress.tls.source=letsEncrypt \
  --set letsEncrypt.email=me@example.org \
  --set letsEncrypt.ingress.class=nginx --set global.cattle.psp.enabled=false
```

```
k get ns
cattle-fleet-clusters-system             Active   25m
cattle-fleet-local-system                Active   25m
cattle-fleet-system                      Active   26m
cattle-global-data                       Active   26m
cattle-global-nt                         Active   26m
cattle-impersonation-system              Active   26m
cattle-system                            Active   29m
cert-manager                             Active   30m
cluster-fleet-local-local-1a3d67d0a899   Active   25m
default                                  Active   53m
fleet-default                            Active   26m
fleet-local                              Active   27m
kube-node-lease                          Active   53m
kube-public                              Active   53m
kube-system                              Active   53m
local                                    Active   26m
p-hfjqf                                  Active   26m
p-xhz55                                  Active   26m
```

```
❯ k get pod -n cattle-system
NAME                              READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
helm-operation-bkt8t              0/2     Completed   0          12m
helm-operation-vjk7p              0/2     Completed   0          12m
rancher-7c655cfbf7-7pcg5          1/1     Running     0          14m
rancher-7c655cfbf7-g4fcx          1/1     Running     0          14m
rancher-7c655cfbf7-tb9r7          1/1     Running     0          14m
rancher-webhook-656cd8b9f-5prv8   1/1     Running     0          12m
```

```
❯ k get ing -n cattle-system
NAME      CLASS    HOSTS           ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
rancher   <none>   dograbbit.org             80, 443   13m
```

I confuse about . How can I access my dograbbit.org in chrome?
It's seem ing doesn't have CLASS.

I want to access the dog rabbit.org.  Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To date rancher will support only eks 1.24